# partial search using Solr EdgeNgramFileterFactory

Tags: search, solr

I am using EdgeNgramFilterFactory for partial search

```html
<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="4" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
```

so if the word is **"sfx"** this will not be stored in index as its length is < 4 and i cannot search it , is there any way to store the words with lenghth < minGramSize in index and make it searchable ???

Using Solr 4.3
Thanks ...

Comment: which version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to change the minGramSize to lower length like to 3 your case.
Or may be you can keep it as 2.

In earlier version (I used 3.3) had the side front and back so I Used it like this.

```
<fieldType name="text_reference" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="50" side="front"/>
      <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="50" side="back"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
       <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

or you can index the text using another field type where you will keep the text as it without ngraming and search in that field as well. Where their wont be any n-gram filter so it the text with length 3 will get indexed.

```
<fieldType name="text_delimeter" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" preserveOriginal="1" catenateAll="1" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
     <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: thanks ,, i done want to reduce minGramSize to < 4 .. I will try having new field...

Comment: I think it is good to keep the minGramSize to 3...Any application goes with minimun of 2 or 3 characters..Dont Know your reason behind not making it 3

Comment: Thanks .. I created a new filed and give a boost to tat filed now its working fine , and also resolved some other issues i had..Thanks once again